# Comprehending Async and Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am still new to JS and I was trying to comprehend `Async and Await`

I went through this amazing Article on web where they [concluded explaining](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es-2017-learn-async-await-by-example-48acc58bad65) this code snippet

```
function doubleAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x * 2);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function addAsync(x) {
  const a = await doubleAfter2Seconds(10);
  const b = await doubleAfter2Seconds(20);
  const c = await doubleAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + a + b + c;
}


addAsync(10).then((sum) => {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Now based on the above article, I was able to draw some conclusion and would love if anyone could verify if it correct or not.

To use `await`, we need to nest it under `Async` function? 
Async solves the chaining problem? but then so does `Promise.all`? so what makes async unique/better?

Comment: _"so what makes async unique/better?"_ - Just change the given example to use `Promise`s and `.then()` calls only and compare both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To use await, we need to nest it under Async function?

yes, `await` keyword is available only in `async` functions

> Async solves the chaining problem?

it makes code looks more straightforward

> but then so does Promise.all?

you still may use it with `await`, e.g.:

```
async function addAsync(x) {
  const [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([
    doubleAfter2Seconds(10), 
    doubleAfter2Seconds(20),  
    doubleAfter2Seconds(30)
  ]);
  return x + a + b + c;
}
```

in this case all promises inside `Promise.all` will be resolved in parallel and you will get results in 2 seconds, instead of 6

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all waits for resolving of every promise in parallel, on the other hand await does it one after the other, that being said if you had many different functions each heavily relying on the value from the previous one you could not use Promise.all in that scenario.